# nopCommerce paypal PDTHandler

Tags: paypal, nopcommerce, paypal-pdt

I have successfully deployed nopCommerce to azure using a shared hosting plan.
All was going ok until I came to attempting to test the paypal payments integration using sandbox

I have connected up my site to paypal using a test seller account, and a test buyer account in the sandbox environment, and have managed to successfully send the buyer to PayPal to complete payment for an item, however the problem occurs on the return

when PayPal tries to redirect to my site, I get an error like this :

> We're sorry, an internal error occurred. 
>   Our supporting staff has been notified of this error and will address the issue shortly

now, I have followed the instructions on the configure paypal section in the admin of nopCommerce to the letter.

in PayPal, auto return is on, the return url is set to   `http://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler`

PDT transfer is on and I have the token copied over to my admin config

I also tried enabling IPN as I was unsure if this was required for this to all work.

the notification URL is set to
`http://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/IPNHandler`

back in nopCommerce admin, ihave the following configured:

use `sandbox - yes`
correct business email
PDT identity token is entered correctly
IPN Handler is as above, although I suspect you can leave blank to default and it would be same as above

and yet... seemingly, I stil receive an error when Paypal attempts to send the sandbox test user back to my site.

Anyone have any suggestions or faced something similar? I saw another thread on stack overflow where someone was having difficulty wiht PDT / IPN and the response was just someone copy-pasting the paypal standard instructions which you find in the nopCommerce admin config of paypal, so that didnt help since i have followed those instructions to the letter already.

thanks in advance

Comment: btw I found what paypal is setting as the return URL link... its    href="http://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler?tx=9ND66961R7349752G&amp;st=Completed&amp;amt=4%2e50&amp;cc=GBP&amp;cm=5f5e95d2%2d07dd%2d4172%2daa56%2d191e21c13aa3&amp;item_number="    ... if any of that is of any use

Comment: Do you have all values set up for your store properly?  Both in Configuration -> Settings -> General & Misc. & Configuration -> Stores?

Answer (score 0):

To find out what went wrong you need to turn off the custom errors mode.

- Open web.config file
- Find out the following line
- Replace it with